# pathos multiprocessing getting AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SomeClass' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'path\to\packageConstructor.py'

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess, pathos

I am trying to understand multiprocessing by a simple task of multiprocessing using `pathos` module but I am getting following error

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'SomeClass' on mp_main' from
>   'path\to\packageConstructor.py'

Here is my full code for review:

```
from random import randint
import os
import pathos
mp = pathos.helpers.mp
prc = pathos.helpers.mp.Process
class SomeClass:
    def m1(self):
        self.objAttr = randint(20000,40000)
        self.selfID = id(self)
        self.m2()
    def m2(self):
        print(os.getpid(), self.objAttr,self.selfID)

    def checkMultiprocessing(self):
        for c in range(10):
            exec(f"p{c} = prc(target=self.m1)")
            exec(f"p{c}.start()")
        for c in range(10):
            exec(f"p{c}.join()")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    SomeClass().checkMultiprocessing()
```

What am I missing?